# Passar cpf para uma função javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Meu campo que carrega o cpf é esse:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cpf, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cpf, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "cpf" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cpf, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

e no botão `submit` eu chamo a `function` no click:

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" onclick="replaceCpf();"/>
```

Minha função js:

```
function replaceCPF(cpf) {
    return cpf.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/, "$1.$2.$3-$4");
}
```

Como posso o parâmetro cpf?

Comment: `onclick="replaceCpf(document.getElementById("cpf").value);"` ?

Comment: Você não precisa do `@id = "cpf"`, pode apagar. O próprio `model.cpf` gera o id.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que vejo do seu template razor, o id do campo é `cpf`. Então você pode pegar o campo e seu valor de dentro da função, com base nesse id. Não faz sentido essa função retornar valor como você fez. Eu faria algo assim:

```
function replaceCpf() {
    var campo = document.getElementById('cpf');
    var cpf = campo.value;
    campo.value = cpf.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/, "$1.$2.$3-$4");
}
```

Outra coisa: o nome da função precisa corresponder na declaração e na chamada! Você usou `replaceCpf` no onclick e `replaceCPF` na declaração. Repare que no código acima já ajustei o nome para não dar problema.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Tirando os problemas de sintaxe js da outra resposta, apenas uma questão de estilo. Eu prefiro evitar misturar js com html. Só não sugeri addEventListener na resposta pra não causar ruído.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve passar o id do campo no replaceCpf(), algo como

`replaceCpf(document.getElementById('cpf'));`

só que dentro da sua função ele não vai receber a string e sim o objeto INPUT do do cpf, então deveria ser feito algo como:

```
function replaceCPF(inpuCpfField) {
    cpf = inputCpfField.text;
    cpf = cpf.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/, "$1.$2.$3-$4");
    inputCpfField.text(cpf);
}
```

PS: não tenho certeza quanto a sintaxe do JS, mas a lógica é essa.